# Windows 10 installer says there's WIndows already installed

Tags: windows-10, usb, installation, windows-installation, windows-installer

**Equipment:**

- Windows Live USB
- Xubuntu USB
- HP Laptop with Xubuntu (see [Broken (probably erased) Windows 10 boot](https://superuser.com/questions/1513069/broken-probably-erased-windows-10-boot) for more info)
  **Problem:**
- Inserting Windows Live USB
- Proceeding to the "Simple installation"
- "This type of installation is unavailable. Windows is already installed"

Comment: You may wish to get the HP Recovery USB as you need the Windows partitions it will build. I have done that here and the manufacturer’s USB worked fine. If you wish to try your USB, try deleting all partitions before installing

Comment: You are getting this message due to the fact, Windows is indeed installed, the installation environment can't detect when an installation cannot be used due to an existing error.  It is not clear what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @John, don't you think it will erase BIOS or something important?

Comment: You can install a blank drive and properly install Windows 10 (I have done that). Basic BIOS is maintained on a motherboard chip. So you should be OK.

Comment: @John, so I basically erase all partitions and install Windows from USB?

Comment: You should be able to do that. Windows 10 was once there and running. It is like replacing a disk drive

Comment: Okay, wait for next question, when I'll screw up with this

Comment: Nevermind, everything is alright now

Comment: So if I convert my first post to an answer, will you accept it?